# Windows 2008 R2 OS 64 bit + MOSS 64 bit SP2 + VS2010 = System.BadImageFormatException

Tags: 2007, search, visual-studio

I am running Visual studio 2010 on OS 64 bit and one of my asp.net web service application that sharepoint code throwing an error.

**Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.**

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the platform selected in your project's properties Build section? It should be Any CPU.

Comment: I did that. still the same. Will SharePoint 2007 64 + Os 64 + Vs2010 will support?